# Handling hidden Objective C errors

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I've come across the below error. This error persists even if I try to use my code on another machine with same version of Xcode 4.2 final.  Can any one help?

Console Output

```
error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2184 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in
function "void macosx_kill_inferior_safe()": 
(os/kern) failure (0x5x) quit
```

Comment: I'd look at earlier and later messages in the console for some clues.  And maybe the OSx guys know where to look for dumps.

Answer (score 3):

The debugger is crashing.    Crashing debuggers are a world of pain.

Looks like you are using gdb.  Try moving to lldb and see if that works around it.

If that doesn't, try nuking your derived data directory as it may be that you have a corrupt symbol that is causing the debugger to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the error is, but googling for the file produces [macosx-nat-inferior.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-967/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c) which describes itself as being a part of GDB.  So assuming it is the same file as on your computer, then diving in to it may help solve your issue.  However that message appears on line 1981 of the file I found .. so I doubt it is the same one as on your computer.  But issues with GDB sound weird.

Comment: Nah -- debugging the debugger is a path rife with madness.   Best to move on and try to workaround the issue.   This isn't a wrong answer, just an answer that is likely to be fruitless.  In my experience, the moment you type `gdb /path/to/my/debug/gdb`, you've already lost. :)